FFMPEG encoding example does not work
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.2/encode_video_8c-example.html
Tried this code on Ubuntu and Windows with the latest FFmpeg build. Both runs fail at ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame); ret gets -22
What causes this issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
